# If $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is a basis of a space V, and $(w_1,..,w_k)$ is l.i in $V$, is it true that the $w_i's$ must span at least k of the $v_j's$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is a basis of a space V, and $(w_1,..,w_k)$ is l.i in $V$, is it true that the $w_i's$ must span at least k of the $v_j's$?

I've been struggling to find a proof, with no succes...

Comment: What do you mean by "the $w_i's$ must span at least k of the $v_j's$"?

Comment: Do you mean "at least $k$ of the $v_j$ lie in the span of the $w_i$"?

Comment: @angryavian Yes, that''s right

Comment: It is easy to construct a counterexample when $k=1$: just pick some $w_1$ different from the $v_j$.

Comment: Here's the definition of "spanning": let $V$ be a vector space and $U$ be a subset of $V$ (usually, we require $U$ is a subspace). The vectors $v_1, \dots, v_k$ in $V$ span $U$ iff each $u \in U$ may be written as a linear combination $u = a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_k v_k$ for some scalars $a_1, \dots, a_k$. As stated, your question doesn't make sense with this definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V=\mathbb R^2$, let $v_1=(1,0)$, let $v_2=(0,1)$, let $k=1$, and let $w_1=(1,1)$. Clearly $(v_1,v_2)$ is a basis for $V$, and $(w_1)$ is linearly independent because $w_1\neq \mathbf{0}$. However,
$$
\text{span}(w_1)=\{(a,a):a\in\mathbb R\}
$$
does not contain $v_1$ or $v_2$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some intuition so that you can think about the proof.

The basis for the vector space $V$ is composed of $n$ linearly independent vectors. That means $dim(V)=n$. So, any $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$ will span this particular vector space.

Now, these $k$ vectors are also linearly independent in $V$. For certain $k\leq n$ since if $k>n$ then the vectors $(v_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot, v_n)$ would not form a basis. Since these $k$ vectors are linearly independent, if $k=n$, then $span(w_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,w_k)=span(v_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,v_n)=V$.

Otherwise, if $k<n$, then $span(w_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,w_k)$ has to be spanned by (at least) $k \quad\!\!\! v_j$'s  .